# what is Module build failed (file-loader) error?

Tags: reactjs, npm

when I run `npm start` for running my reactjs project, this result is shown:

one error per each svg file in images folder!

[image: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):]

what is my mistake?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was used nodejs 18 and now I downgrade the nodejs to v14 and it's work !

Answer (score 0):

i was working on node js v20 and now i downgrade to v14 using nvm and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).